# Why does my Recycler View crashes while scrolling in TabLayout?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout inside a TabLayout(second TabLayout is in a Fragment). Now when I switch tabs in the child TabLayout the recycler view is already loaded but it crashes when I scroll the recycler view.
My recycler adapter uses 2 lists (2 different model classes) and 2 view holders.
I am fetching the data from the firebase database.

Inner Fragment class that contains another TabLayout.

```
public class CommentaryFragment extends Fragment {

    private TeamDetails mTeamADetails, mTeamBDetails;
    private InningsScore mInningsScoreA, mInningsScoreB;
    private ArrayList<PlayerDetails> mTeamASquad, mTeamBSquad;
    private ArrayList<Commentary> mCommentaryListA, mCommentaryListB;
    private List<TeamDetails> mTeamDetailsList;
    private List<InningsScore> mInningsScoreList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_commentary, container, false);
       

        setupDatabase();
        getDetailsFromDatabase();
        setupTabIcons();

        return view;
    }

    private void getDetailsFromDatabase() {
        mDatabaseReferenceRound
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.A))) {
                            mTeamADetails = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(TeamDetails.class);

                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.squad)).getChildren()) {
                                PlayerDetails playerDetails = snapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(PlayerDetails.class);
                                mTeamASquad.add(playerDetails);
                            }

                            if (dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).exists()) {
                                mInningsScoreA = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.total_score)).getValue(InningsScore.class);

                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.commentary)).getChildren()) {
                                    Commentary commentary = snapshot.getValue(Commentary.class);
                                    mCommentaryListA.add(commentary);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.B))) {
                            mTeamBDetails = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(TeamDetails.class);

                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.squad)).getChildren()) {
                                PlayerDetails playerDetails = snapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(PlayerDetails.class);
                                mTeamBSquad.add(playerDetails);
                            }

                            if (dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).exists()) {
                                mInningsScoreB = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.total_score)).getValue(InningsScore.class);

                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.commentary)).getChildren()) {
                                    Commentary commentary = snapshot.getValue(Commentary.class);
                                    mCommentaryListB.add(commentary);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        mDatabaseReferenceRound
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mTeamDetailsList.add(mTeamADetails);
                        mTeamDetailsList.add(mTeamBDetails);
                        mInningsScoreList.add(mInningsScoreA);
                        mInningsScoreList.add(mInningsScoreB);
                        updateWidgets();
                    }
        }
}
```

This is a Full Fragment in the Child TabLayout that is causing the problem.

```
public class FullFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full, container, false);
        mCommentaryListA = new ArrayList<>();
        mCommentaryListB = new ArrayList<>();
        mEndOfOversListA = new ArrayList<>();
        mEndOfOversListB = new ArrayList<>();
        mTeamASquad = new ArrayList<>();
        mTeamBSquad = new ArrayList<>();


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mTournamentDetails = getArguments().getParcelable(getString(R.string.tournament_details));
            mRoundName = getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.round_name));
            mTeamReference = getArguments().getString(getString(R.string.teams));
        }

        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDatabaseReferenceRound = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(getString(R.string.tournament))
                .child(mUser.getUid())
                .child(mTournamentDetails.getUUID())
                .child(getString(R.string.rounds))
                .child(mRoundName);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.full_recyclerView);
        mRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.full_swipeRefresh);
        mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.full_progressBar);
        getDetailsFromDatabase();

        return view;
    }

    private void getDetailsFromDatabase() {
        mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        mDatabaseReferenceRound
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.match))) {
                            mCurrentBattingTeam = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.current_batting_team)).getValue(String.class);
                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.A))) {
                            mTeamADetails = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(TeamDetails.class);
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.squad)).getChildren()) {
                                PlayerDetails playerDetails = snapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(PlayerDetails.class);
                                mTeamASquad.add(playerDetails);
                            }

                            if (dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).exists()) {
                                mCommentaryListA.clear();
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.commentary)).getChildren()) {
                                    Commentary commentary = snapshot.getValue(Commentary.class);
                                    mCommentaryListA.add(commentary);
                                }

                                mEndOfOversListA.clear();
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.end_of_over)).getChildren()) {
                                    EndOfOver endOfOver = snapshot.getValue(EndOfOver.class);
                                    mEndOfOversListA.add(endOfOver);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.B))) {
                            mTeamBDetails = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(TeamDetails.class);

                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.squad)).getChildren()) {
                                PlayerDetails playerDetails = snapshot.child(getString(R.string.details)).getValue(PlayerDetails.class);
                                mTeamBSquad.add(playerDetails);
                            }

                            if (dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).exists()) {
                                mCommentaryListB.clear();
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.commentary)).getChildren()) {
                                    Commentary commentary = snapshot.getValue(Commentary.class);
                                    mCommentaryListB.add(commentary);
                                }

                                mEndOfOversListB.clear();
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.batting)).child(getString(R.string.end_of_over)).getChildren()) {
                                    EndOfOver endOfOver = snapshot.getValue(EndOfOver.class);
                                    mEndOfOversListB.add(endOfOver);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

        mDatabaseReferenceRound
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        updateWidgets();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateWidgets() {
        if (mCurrentBattingTeam.equals(mTeamADetails.getUUID())) {
            mAdapter = new SummaryCommentaryAdapter(getContext(), mCommentaryListA, mEndOfOversListA, mTeamADetails,
                    mTeamASquad, mTeamBSquad, getString(R.string.full));
        } else {
            mAdapter = new SummaryCommentaryAdapter(getContext(), mCommentaryListB, mEndOfOversListB, mTeamBDetails,
                    mTeamBSquad, mTeamASquad, getString(R.string.full));
        }
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
```

This is the adapter class that uses 2 lists with 2 different ViewHolder Class.

```
public class SummaryCommentaryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private int mBallCounter = 0, mEndOverCounter = 0;
    private int flag = 0;   //FLAG = 0 BALLS     // FLAG = 1 END OF OVER
    private ArrayList<Commentary> commentaries = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Commentary> mCommentaryList;
    private ArrayList<EndOfOver> mEndOfOversList;
    private TeamDetails mTeamDetails;
    private ArrayList<PlayerDetails> mBattingSquad, mBowlingSquad;
    private List<String> typeOfOutList;
    private String mFragmentName;

    public SummaryCommentaryAdapter(Context context, List<Commentary> commentaryList, ArrayList<EndOfOver> endOfOversList,
                                    TeamDetails teamDetails, ArrayList<PlayerDetails> battingSquad,
                                    ArrayList<PlayerDetails> bowlingSquad, String fragmentName) {
        mContext = context;
        mCommentaryList = commentaryList;
        mEndOfOversList = endOfOversList;
        mTeamDetails = teamDetails;
        mBattingSquad = battingSquad;
        mBowlingSquad = bowlingSquad;
        mFragmentName = fragmentName;

        typeOfOutList = Arrays.asList(mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types_of_out));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (flag == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.summary_commentary_detail, parent, false);
            return new BallsViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_end_of_over, parent, false);
            return new EndOfOverViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (flag == 0) {
            if (mFragmentName.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.summary))) {
                Commentary commentary = mCommentaryList.get(mBallCounter);
                ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mBallNumber.setText(String.format("%.1f", commentary.getBallNumber()));

                //CHANGE BACKGROUND OF mSCORE ACCORDING TO THE RUNS SCORED.

                if (commentary.getRuns().equals("0")) {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), " no run"));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().equals("1")) {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), commentary.getRuns() + " run"));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().equals("2") || commentary.getRuns().equals("3")) {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), commentary.getRuns() + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.runs)));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().equals("4")) {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), "FOUR"));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().equals("6")) {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), "SIX"));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().contains("WD")) {
                    String a = String.valueOf(commentary.getRuns().charAt(0));
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText("WD");
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(),
                            "(wide ball), " + a + "runs"));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().contains("NB")) {
                    String a = String.valueOf(commentary.getRuns().charAt(0));
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText("NB");
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(),
                            "(no ball), " + a + "runs"));
                } else if (commentary.getRuns().contains("LB")) {
                    String a = String.valueOf(commentary.getRuns().charAt(0));
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText("LB");
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(),
                            "(leg bye), " + a + "runs"));
                } else if (commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(0)) || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(1))
                        || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(2)) || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(3))
                        || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(4)) || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(5))
                        || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(6)) || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(7))
                        || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(8)) || commentary.getRuns().equals(typeOfOutList.get(9))) {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText("W");
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(),
                            "OUT, " + commentary.getRuns()));
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mExtraDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mExtraDetails.setText(getWicketDetail(commentary.getWicket()));

                } else if (commentary.getRuns().contains("B")) {
                    String a = String.valueOf(commentary.getRuns().charAt(0));
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText("B");
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(),
                            "(bye), " + a + "runs"));
                } else {
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText("W");
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                            commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(),
                            "OUT, " + commentary.getRuns()));

                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mExtraDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mExtraDetails.setText(getWicketDetail(commentary.getWicket()));
                }
                flag = 0;
            } else if (mFragmentName.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.boundary))) {
                Commentary commentary = commentaries.get(position);
                if (commentary.isBoundary()) {
                    if (commentary.getRuns().equals("4")) {
                        ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                        ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                        ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                                commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), "FOUR"));

                    } else if (commentary.getRuns().equals("6")) {
                        ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mScore.setText(commentary.getRuns());
                        ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                        ((BallsViewHolder) holder).mSentence.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.summary_commentary_placeholder,
                                commentary.getBowler().getName(), commentary.getBatsman().getName(), "SIX"));
                    }
                }
                flag = 0;
            }
            if ((mCommentaryList.get(mBallCounter).getBallNumber() % 1) >= 0.58) {
                flag = 1;
            }
            mBallCounter++;

        } else {
            // END OF OVER.
            EndOfOver endOfOver = mEndOfOversList.get(mEndOverCounter);
            ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mOverNumber.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.end_over_placeholder, endOfOver.getOverNumber()));
            ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mRunsWickets.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.runs_wickets_placeholder, endOfOver.getOverRuns(),
                    endOfOver.getOverWickets()));
            ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mTeamStat.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.team_stat_placeholder, mTeamDetails.getName(),
                    endOfOver.getTeamRuns(), endOfOver.getTeamWickets()));

            for (int k = 0; k < mBattingSquad.size(); k++) {
                if (endOfOver.getBatsman1().getUUID().equals(mBattingSquad.get(k).getUUID())) {
                    ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mPlayerAName.setText(mBattingSquad.get(k).getName());
                    ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mPlayerAStat.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.individual_runs_placeholder,
                            endOfOver.getBatsman1().getRuns(), endOfOver.getBatsman1().getBalls()));
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < mBattingSquad.size(); k++) {
                if (endOfOver.getBatsman2().getUUID().equals(mBattingSquad.get(k).getUUID())) {
                    ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mPlayerBName.setText(mBattingSquad.get(k).getName());
                    ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mPlayerBStat.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.individual_runs_placeholder,
                            endOfOver.getBatsman2().getRuns(), endOfOver.getBatsman2().getBalls()));
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < mBowlingSquad.size(); k++) {
                if (endOfOver.getBowler().getUUID().equals(mBowlingSquad.get(k).getUUID())) {
                    ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mBowlerName.setText(mBowlingSquad.get(k).getName());
                    ((EndOfOverViewHolder) holder).mBowlerStat.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.bowler_stats_placeholder,
                            endOfOver.getBowler().getOvers(), endOfOver.getBowler().getMaiden(), endOfOver.getBowler().getRuns(),
                            endOfOver.getBowler().getWickets()));
                    break;
                }
            }
            mEndOverCounter++;
            flag = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mCommentaryList.size() + mEndOfOversList.size());
    }

    static class BallsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mBallNumber, mScore, mSentence, mExtraDetails;

        public BallsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mBallNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentary_ballNumber);
            mScore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentary_score);
            mSentence = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentary_sentence);
            mExtraDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentary_extraDetails);
        }
    }

    static class EndOfOverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mOverNumber, mRunsWickets, mTeamStat, mPlayerAName, mPlayerBName, mPlayerAStat, mPlayerBStat;
        private TextView mBowlerName, mBowlerStat;

        public EndOfOverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mOverNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_overNumber);
            mRunsWickets = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_runsWickets);
            mTeamStat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_teamStat);
            mPlayerAName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_playerAName);
            mPlayerAStat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_playerAStat);
            mPlayerBName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_playerBName);
            mPlayerBStat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_playerBStat);
            mBowlerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_bowlerName);
            mBowlerStat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.endOfOver_bowlerStat);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat details of the error.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.k3ptechnologies.undefeatdsports, PID: 9087
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.k3ptechnologies.undefeatdsports.Matches.Scorecard.MatchFragments.Summary.SummaryCommentaryAdapter$BallsViewHolder cannot be cast to com.k3ptechnologies.undefeatdsports.Matches.Scorecard.MatchFragments.Summary.SummaryCommentaryAdapter$EndOfOverViewHolder
        at com.k3ptechnologies.undefeatdsports.Matches.Scorecard.MatchFragments.Summary.SummaryCommentaryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SummaryCommentaryAdapter.java:194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the log

```
Matches.Scorecard.MatchFragments.Summary.SummaryCommentaryAdapter$BallsViewHolder cannot be cast to com.k3ptechnologies.undefeatdsports.Matches.Scorecard.MatchFragments.Summary.SummaryCommentaryAdapter$EndOfOverViewHolder
```

It looks like one of your condition (`flag=0`) is making it choose `BallsViewHolder` over `EndOfOverViewHolder`

You should look at how to properly handle multiple `ViewTypes` in a `Recyclerview`: [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: The link you have mentioned contains only one  dataset. Mine contains two datasets with two view holder for each one.

Comment: You just need to add your list, but use the link as a base